# How to integrate paypal in Zend Framework 1.12?

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, sandbox

I know you may ask why I don't try to google the solution first, now I can say that I already googled for it, unfortunately it come out too many solutions and different ways to do that.

My situation is like this, I want to allow those clients to be able to subscribe my service **annually**.

From [this link](http://devzone.zend.com/370/choosing-the-right-paypal-solution/), they suggested too much solution, I don't know which 1 is fit to my situation. And of course, I want to use the free service *(direct debit need monthly fee)*.

Which mean that, I want to store the transaction# into my db every year when the service subscribed by my client is expired, and it automatically send an acknowledgement email to clients and my company's email.

In summary,

1. Which way is suitable to my situation.
2. Is cron job need in this case? or just need to use recurring payment that provided by paypal?
3. Is there any **link** or example *(i.e. coding implementation in sandbox)*?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: start with https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-how-to-guides

Answer (score 0):

You could use PayPal Payments Pro with the Direct Payment API to process the initial credit card transactions.  Then you can store the transaction in your system, and set your system to run a cron job and perform a reference transaction API call to charge the buyer again.  This will give you the effects of setting up a recurring payment profile without actually having the service through PayPal.

However, if you prefer to do less coding and setting up your system to perform cron jobs and etc, then you could just sign up for PayPal's recurring payments/recurring billing services, which would allow you to just make an API call to PayPal to set up a profile.  Then PayPal will take of billing your buyers when they should be billed.

Answer (score 0):

HI I have made code for ZF

> ```
> public function processPaymentAction()
> {
>     $methodName = 'CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile';
>     // from nvpHeader function
>     $API_Endpoint = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';
>     $version = '65.2';
> ```

```
    // But you can use here your own Sandbox API credentials of Business account
    // and you can get through Payapl Sandbox API Credentials Link on Left.

    $API_UserName = 'platfo_1255077030_biz_api1.gmail.com';
    $API_Password = '1255077037';
    $API_Signature = 'Abg0gYcQyxQvnf2HDJkKtA-p6pqhA1k-KTYE0Gcy1diujFio4io5Vqjf';
    $subject = '';
    global $nvp_Header, $AUTH_token, $AUTH_signature, $AUTH_timestamp;
    $nvpHeaderStr = "";

    //pr($this->data);die;
    //$this->data['User']['paymentType']
    $paymentType = urlencode('Sale');
    $firstName = urlencode("Jaskaran");
    $lastName = urlencode("Singh");
    $creditCardType = urlencode("Visa");
    $creditCardNumber = urlencode("4798720058660243");
    $expDateMonth =urlencode(11);

    // Month must be padded with leading zero
    $padDateMonth = str_pad($expDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $expDateYear = urlencode(2015);
    $cvv2Number = urlencode(962);
    $address1 = urlencode("1 Main St");
    $address2 = urlencode("");
    $city = urlencode("San Jose");
    $state = urlencode("CA");
    $zip = urlencode(95131);
    $amount = urlencode(1.00);

//  $init_amount = urlencode($this->data['User']['pack_price']);

    $currencyCode="USD";

    $profileDesc = urlencode("Welcome to the world of shopping where you get everything");
    $billingPeriod = urlencode("Week");
    $billingFrequency = urlencode(4);
    $totalBillingCycles = urlencode(0);

    ################# Commented as we need to define through Admin ##############

    $profileStartDateDay = 10;
    // Day must be padded with leading zero
    $padprofileStartDateDay = str_pad($profileStartDateDay, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $profileStartDateMonth = 02;
    // Month must be padded with leading zero
    $padprofileStartDateMonth = str_pad($profileStartDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $profileStartDateYear = 2015;

    $profileStartDate = urlencode($profileStartDateYear . '-' . $padprofileStartDateMonth . '-' . $padprofileStartDateDay . 'T00:00:00Z');

    //string from nvpHeader
    $nvpHeaderStr = "&PWD=".urlencode($API_Password)."&USER=".urlencode($API_UserName)."&SIGNATURE=".urlencode($API_Signature);

    $nvpstr="&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber&EXPDATE=". $padDateMonth.$expDateYear."&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state".
    "&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=US&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyCode&PROFILESTARTDATE=$profileStartDate&DESC=$profileDesc&BILLINGPERIOD=$billingPeriod&BILLINGFREQUENCY=$billingFrequency&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=$totalBillingCycles";

    $nvpstr = $nvpHeaderStr.$nvpstr;
    //check if version is included in $nvpStr else include the version.
    if(strlen(str_replace('VERSION=','', strtoupper($nvpstr))) == strlen($nvpstr)) 
    {
        $nvpstr = "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . $nvpstr;
    }
    $nvpreq="METHOD=".urlencode($methodName).$nvpstr;


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //$nvpreq=”METHOD=”.urlencode($methodName).$nvpStr;

    //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$nvpreq);

    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
    $nvpResArray=$this->deformatNVP($response);
    $nvpReqArray=$this->deformatNVP($nvpreq);


    if (curl_errno($ch)) 
    {
        echo "cURL Error";
        die;
        // moving to display page to display curl errors
        $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
        $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);
        //$location = "APIError.php";
        //header("Location: $location");
    } 
    else 
    {
        //closing the curl
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    #### Checking error ###
    if(!empty($nvpResArray))
    {
        if($nvpResArray['ACK'] == 'Failure')
        {
            echo "ERROR : ". $errmsg = $nvpResArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"];
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($nvpResArray);
            die;
        }
    }

    // Print this array you will get some necessary info
    ################ Starting data insert##################

    if($nvpResArray['ACK'] == 'Success')
    {
        echo 'Success';
        print_r($nvpResArray);
        die;
        // save data into tables for Recurring Profile
    }



}

############### Function deformatNVP #########
/** This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
 * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
 * @nvpstr is NVPString.
 * @nvpArray is Associative Array.
 */
function deformatNVP ($nvpstr)
{
    $intial = 0;
    $nvpArray = array();
    while (strlen($nvpstr)) {
        //postion of Key
        $keypos = strpos($nvpstr, '=');
        //position of value
        $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr, '&') ? strpos($nvpstr, '&') : strlen(
        $nvpstr);
        /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
        $keyval = substr($nvpstr, $intial, $keypos);
        $valval = substr($nvpstr, $keypos + 1, $valuepos - $keypos - 1);
        //decoding the respose
        $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] = urldecode($valval);
        $nvpstr = substr($nvpstr, $valuepos + 1, strlen($nvpstr));
    }
    return $nvpArray;
}
function formAutorization ($auth_token, $auth_signature, $auth_timestamp)
{
    $authString = "token=" . $auth_token . ",signature=" . $auth_signature .
     ",timestamp=" . $auth_timestamp;
    return $authString;
}
```